# How to dockerize .NET6 AWS Lambda project with dependent class library projects

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have four projects in one solution:

- `App.Data` - class library
- `App.Core` - class library
- `App.LambdaOne` - AWS Lambda project
- `App.LambdaTwo` - AWS Lambda project

The solution structure looks like this:

Solution:

- App.Data
- App.Core
- App.LambdaOne

  - Dockerfile
- App.LambdaTwo

  - Dockerfile

I am trying to create two docker images for `App.LambdaOne` and `App.LambdaTwo`, so I can deploy them separately.

So far, I have got a simple lambda project without any dependent project works using the Dockfile below.

Docker command in `App.LambdaSimple`'s directory

```
docker build -t LambdaSimpleImage .
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["App.LambdaSimple.csproj", "App.LambdaSimple/"]
RUN dotnet restore "App.LambdaSimple.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/App.LambdaSimple"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "App.LambdaSimple.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App.AWSLambdaOne.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD ["App.LambdaSimple::App.LambdaSimple.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

But the tricky part is that **`App.LambdaOne`depend on `App.Data` and `App.Core`**. I tried to modify the working sample to deploy `App.LambdaOne`, but no luck so far. By running the same Docker command. Errors occurred, I have added those to the comments

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["App.AWSLambdaOne.csproj", "App.AWSLambdaOne/"]
#Error: cannot find App.Data.csproj
COPY ["App.Data.csproj", "App.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "App.LambdaOne.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/App.AWSLambdaOne"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "App.AWSLambdaOne.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App.AWSLambdaOne.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD ["App.AWSLambdaOne::App.AWSLambdaOne.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

I can understand why the error occurred, which is due to the Docker Context being under App.AWSLambdaOne. But cannot find any solution to fix it.

A partial solution I found is to have the Dockerfile at the Solution level, so Docker context includes all projects when building it. However, it does not fit my purpose since I want to build two images for different projects.

I have been searching for a clue in the last two days, it is driving me crazy. May I ask if it is possible to achieve what I am after with the existing project structure? If not can anyone please point me to the right direction?

THANKS A LOT in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access host files outside the build context, so you *must* move the build context up a directory to be able to access the code for the other projects. So to start, let's change the build command to

```
docker build -t LambdaSimpleImage ..
```

Now we need to adjust the Dockerfile so it fits the new context

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:6 AS base

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim as build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["App.LambdaSimple/App.LambdaSimple.csproj", "App.LambdaSimple/"]
COPY ["App.Data/App.Data.csproj", "App.Data/"]
COPY ["App.Core/App.Core.csproj", "App.Core/"]

RUN dotnet restore "App.LambdaSimple/App.LambdaSimple.csproj"

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "App.LambdaSimple/App.LambdaSimple.csproj" --configuration Release --output /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "App.LambdaSimple/App.LambdaSimple.csproj" \
            --configuration Release \ 
            --runtime linux-x64 \
            --self-contained false \ 
            --output /app/publish \
            -p:PublishReadyToRun=true  

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
CMD ["App.LambdaSimple::App.LambdaSimple.Function::FunctionHandler"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hans! The image is successfully built locally, but I am not able to test it locally somehow, will try to deploy it to check. will come back to mark this as the answer if everything goes well! Thanks again.